# Multi language full text: Which stemming [Snowball] language should be used?

Tags: stemming, full-text-search, snowball

Which stemming language I should be using if I want to support all
language full text search. As far as I know the index need to created
using that specific stemming language to support search with that
language, but this is not possible for me as my search program may
contain different languages

--
Manoj

Answer (score 0):

Stemming is not a concept applicable to all languages. It is not, for example, applicable in Chinese. But to languages of the Indo-European group (and most of the stemmers on Snowball site are for Indo-European languages), a common pattern of word structure does emerge. Assuming words are written left to right, the stem, or root of a word is on the left, and zero or more suffixes may be added on the right. If the root is modified by this process it will normally be at its right hand end. And also prefixes may be added on the left.

> @Resource: Snowball Website